# why do game textures that shouldn't be transparent have an alpha channel?

Tags: texturing, transparency

observe

[image]

I have seen alpha layers in diffuse, normal, and specular maps. what purpose does it serve and is it useful in blender in any way?

Answer (score 3):

This channel can be interpreted by the game engine as grayscale data and used for any purpose like a subsurface scattering map, which may be what is happening here.  This is called *Channel Packing*.

Reference: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/ChannelPacking

Comment: does this channel affect the base color? and if this is a SSS map can it be plugged into the subsurface node? what about normal and specular maps, does this channel affect those nodes?

Comment: I don't think it should, the color socket is RGB channels only.  You can take the alpha output and use it however you want, any of the gray sockets on the Principled BSDF will accept grayscale data.  The default SSS settings probably won't give you the results you expect, you'll have to mess around with it